# How to set the login session in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do you manually set the login session in MVC 4? I have a method that checks if a user is valid and returns true or false to the client, but how can I set the session so methods that have the [Authorize] attribute will allow in future requests from this user?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        var isUserValid = SecurityManager.IsUserValid(userName, password);
        if (isUserValid )
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true); 

        return isUserValid ;
    }
```

Comment: You set the FormsAuthentication cookie.  This is provided in the default template of a basic MVC app.

Comment: Ok, so just FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true) should do it, right? How does this work?  My client is an Angular application, so wondering how this makes future requests work. Is there a cookie that gets set on the browser? How does the server know that future requests are from the same person?

Comment: Perhaps the name SetAuth *COOKIE* might give a clue as to the answer of whether or not it sets a cookie?  That's how cookies work, they get sent with future requests until they expire.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Tried setting the auth cookie, but requests are still not able to access methods marked with [Authorize]. I've updated my code.

Comment: It depends on which of the various authentication systems that Microsoft bundle with new VS projects you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, check your web.config file for the FormAuthentication. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add  name="EFDbContext"  connectionString="Data  Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial
              Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True"
              providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="Email.WriteAsFile" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="∼/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: This was it, thank you.  I had to specify the mode in the config file.